# Get rows which are related to the searched row, by specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I am trying to implement a sql query to below scenario,

| user_id | nic_number | reg_number | full_name | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B123 | 12345 | 1212 | John | 123 |
| B124 | 12346 | 1213 | Peter | 124 |
| B125 | 12347 | 1214 | Darln | 125 |
| B123 | 12345 | 1212 | John | 126 |
| B123 | 12345 | 1212 | John | 127 |

In the subscribers table there can be rows with same `user_id` , `nic_number` , `reg_number` , `full_name`. But the code is different.

First -> get the user who have same `code` i have typed in the query ( i have implemented a query for that and it is working fine)

Second -> Then in that data i need to find the related rows (check by `nic_number`, and  `reg_number`) and display only those related rows. That means in the below query I have got the data for `code` = `123`. Which will show the first row of the table.
But I need to display only the rest of the rows which have the same `nic_number` or `reg_number`  for the searched `code` only once.
That means the last 2 rows of the table.

```
select code,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct trim(nic_number)) as nic_number,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct trim(reg_number)) as reg_number,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct trim(full_name)) as full_name from subscribers
where code like lower(concat('123')) group by code;
```

I need to implement sql query for this scenario by changing the above query.(Only one query, without joins or triggers).
I have tried this for a long time and unable to get the result. If anyone of you help me to get the result it will be very helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you saying that the query cannot have JOINs?

Comment: @Craig I am trying to implement this for a client project. Even I don't know why but the client specifically mentioned that the queries need to be simple without any joints or triggers or procedures.

Comment: I would probably be questioning the requirement to have no JOINs, as it doesn't really make sense as a thing to exclude from a query requirement.  (As I said, triggers and procedures I can understand if someone said that - but not JOINs).  I wonder if your client perhaps thinks that JOINs are doing something that they are not .....?

Comment: You know ` CLIENTS`..... Some times they think that they know more than a software engineer. They give stupid requirements like these.

Comment: which version of mysql? 8.x ?

Comment: @MtwStark 8.0.22

Comment: why you have two times the column code in your output?

Comment: @MtwStark I don't understand. What do you mean by 'two times the column code'. Code is like a primary key in here.

Comment: In your output select you have written two times the column code (the 1st and the last), also I'm not sure code is a PK in your table because the error "subquery returns more than one row" means it is duplicated

Comment: Oh. Sorry that's a mistake. I have edited that. Thank-you for the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine nic and reg numbers in a unique key to get your records.

**EDITED**
to extract only related rows and not the one searched by code,
by the way, code seems not to be unique in subscribers table.

```
select 
    code,
    trim(nic_number) as nic_number,
    trim(reg_number) as reg_number,
    trim(full_name) as full_name,
    trim(code) as code 
from 
    subscribers s1
where 
    code <> lower(trim('123')) 
    and trim(nic_number) + '|' + trim(reg_number) IN (
        select trim(nic_number) + '|' + trim(reg_number)
        from subscribers
        where code = lower(trim('123'))
    )
```

Comment: If I use this query I am getting `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: it means that code is not different for each row in subscribers table

Comment: What i want to display as output is.. If i give code as 123 it need to check the `nic_number` and `reg_number` and show only the related rows. That means in the above table there are 2 other rows which have the same `nic_number` and `reg_number`.  The query need to display only those 2 data. (not the one we searched)

Comment: This edited code is showing the the data of the searched one too

Comment: Is there any ways to show related rows but not the searched row data?

Comment: are you sure?  pay attention to code <> lower(trim('123')) (not equal)

Comment: Yes. It is showing the data of the searched row too.

Comment: Oh... I'll check. May be its the issue in my mysql server. I'll restart the machine and check. Thankyou so much for your guidance .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have specified "without joins" - I get that you may not want to have triggers on a table (which you don't need to achieve this anyway), but a JOIN is standard SQL syntax that will help you achieve the result you are after.

Try:

```
SELECT
s1.code, s1.nic_number, s1.reg_number, s1.full_name
FROM subscribers s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT nic_number, reg_number
    FROM subscribers
    WHERE code = '123'
) s2
ON s1.nic_number = s2.nic_number
AND s1.reg_number = s2.reg_number
WHERE s1.code <> '123';
```

Or, if you really need to achieve it with no JOINs at all, then you're just doubling-up the sub-query that you need to include:

```
SELECT
s1.code, s1.nic_number, s1.reg_number, s1.full_name
FROM subscribers s1
WHERE s1.nic_number IN
(
    SELECT nic_number FROM subscribers
    WHERE code = '123'
)
AND s1.reg_number IN
(
    SELECT reg_number FROM subscribers
    WHERE code = '123'
)
AND s1.code <> '123';
```

The latter query is not necessarily ideal, but it still achieves the desired result.

Comment: The thing here is I don't want to hard code the `nic_number` or `reg_number`.  A query that will automatically find the related `nic_number` and 'reg_number` of the entered code and display the results.

Comment: @Deepika - well, you will need to incorporate the necessary parameters into the query.  I was just using the same sample code ('123') as your example.  I don't know anything about where this query is being run (eg. PHP, some other app, report?).  As to how you add the parameter for the "code", that will be dependent on how you're developing the overall solution

Comment: And, of course, the "nic_number" and "reg_number" are not hard-coded in the answer that I've given - only the '123' code.  So as long as you can specify parameters when your application or report is executing the query, then you'll take the "code" that the user enters (or chooses) and use that to compare with "code"

Comment: Thank-you so much. I'll continue form this.

Comment: But when i try to run this I am getting this error `Column 'nic_number' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Sorry - I just updated the answer with the relevant prefixes for each column

Comment: A subquery is unlikely to be beneficial here